# I want to create a CSS layout with full page height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a single page application. I want to create a layout where there are `multiple radio boxes / buttons` centered on a full page.[image: centered buttons]
User clicks one button, that button is kept and moved to header with sub options now displayed centered.[image: centered sub options]
Finally user selects a sub option and the sub option menu moves to the left and a sub option description panel takes up most of the space.[image: suboption description]
I have little to no CSS experience though I am comfortable working with jQuery/JS.

Is there a framework I could use or how can I proceed with this layout?

Here is what I've reached till now [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k1afs6g/)

Comment: Hi Ramandeep, please post your current code or your attempts to help stackoverflow community figuring out your issue, I recommend to read [ask]

Comment: I tried and found fixed layouts using bootstrap and some other css frameworks. Just don't know enough CSS to make them change their height/width while adding more components. Sorry if I offended you.

Comment: @Peter I created the final layout https://jsfiddle.net/0k1afs6g/, but I am not sure how to have adjusting width/height. I am not even sure if it's the correct approach I used.

Comment: great! I edited your question by adding  you jsfiddle  to make it clearer , please accept the edit

Comment: You have some issues in the HTML structure I will try to solve to get closer to the desired results

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications on your HTML code and then used some jquery code to illustrate the main idea

First you have to make the options and option contents nested in each other like:

Option1 -> option 1.1 -> option 1.1 contents

have to be like

```
<ul class='level1'>
  <li>option
     <ul class='level2'>
        <li>option1.1
           <div class='content'>test</div>
        </li>
     <ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0k1afs6g/2/) the current results